# Installation stuck on creating ext4 file system # 1

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Elitebook 8470p. I got no problem on installing it until I got to creating ext4 file system.

It just got stuck on it for like half an hour, then I force closed the computer, because it was not proceeding. Later I tried the installation again and same thing happened.

What should I do? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I was installing kali linux
I found a solution !

Its actually quite simple.

1. Boot into a live instance of any OS (can be the same one you are installing)
2. Go into the files and completely format the disk you wanted to install your linux on . If they give you an option for the file system just choose ext4
3. It should be done in a matter of a second , your drive wil dissapear but restart and install it this time
4. Give it at least 10 mins
5. It should be installing now !!